# retrieving session variable from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

Is is possible to retrieve a Session variable from a different controller it was created from?

I create this in my Account controller

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"] = sessionGuid;
```

and from a different controller I'm trying

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"] != null)
{
    return Json(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"].ToString());
}
    return null;
```

which always returns `null`.

as a Test I added some code to my Login controller and in that part i do get the value out of it

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"] != null)
    {
        test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"].ToString();
    }
        else
    {
        test = "no";
    }
```

i always got the actual result, not the"no" part of the code

Comment: [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp). You are probably not saving/setting the session state correctly

Answer (score 1):

For some reason its different into how i have to access the session, at the other controller i changed to this code and it worked

```
if (HttpContext.Session["Session"] != null)
{
  return Json(HttpContext.Session["Session"].ToString());
}
return null;
```

Comment: I shared a link earlier in an comment to your question. Read that to understand the reason.

Comment: There's a difference between `HttpContext.Session` and `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Answer (score 0):

if controller is within the same website/virtual directory then YES, however if you are saying your session was created in a different site and you trying to access it within a controller which belongs to different site then you cannot.

Comment: both of them are created in the same site, and even though i am getting null

Comment: try this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1926258.aspx?The+Session+object+is+null+in+ASP+NET+MVC+4+webapplication+once+deployed+to+IIS+7+W+2008+R2+